# General SOCKS server failure while using tor proxy

Tags: socks, proxy

I am proxying traffic over tor, so letter on when I need to call localhost port, it gives failure error.

```
def create_connection(self, address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

def getVideoTrend(self):

    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    socket.create_connection = self.create_connection
    #some code
    Mongo.SaveEntity()
```

SaveEntity contains:

```
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 27017
self.client = MongoClient(hostname, port)
```

which gives

```
  File "radurl.py", line 110, in getVideoTrend
    MongoDbOpp().saveEntity(final_result)    
  File "/root/Documents/scraping/radurls/mongo_operation.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.client = MongoClient(hostname, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 377, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

**I understand the reason behind this error, that mongo attempts to connect to local control port, gets proxied through a tor exit node.**

Is there any solution to this prob?

Or I can terminate tor session after before Mongo operation?

Answer (score 2):

While Tor has a builtin SOCKS proxy, it doesn't have common features of a SOCKS proxy like creating rules based on the target host or overriding how to resolve a host.

No you can't turn off Tor from the SOCKS proxy because Tor *is* the SOCKS proxy.

In your case, you'd have to create two separate connections functions, one for localhost that doesn't use a SOCKS proxy and others that use Tor for scraping websites.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use an intermediate socks agent on 127.0.0.2 for example, and there your magic goes : you're passing all the localhost stuff directly, leaving the rest for Tor.